# SQL query to find whoever has a skill what other skill do they have?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCoKR.png)

I have two tables :

1. UserInfo
2. Skill

and the join table between them called `UserSkill` as you can see at the 
right part of the diagram.

I want to know whoever knows or is skillful in Java, what else he is skillful at. I mean for example I know java, Go, PHP, python and user number 2 knows java and python and CSS. So the answer to the question: whoever knows java what else he knows would be GO, PHP, Python and CSS.

It's like recommendation systems for example whoever but this product what else do they bought? Like what we have in amazon ..

What would be the best query for this ?

Thank you

More information:

**UserInfo**

```
U-id   U-name
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

**SkillInfo**

```
S-id    S-Name
1       Java
2       GO
3       PHP
4       Python
5       CSS
```

**UserSkill**:

```
U-id    S-id
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
2        1
2        4
2        5
```

Comment: You mention a diagram but haven't attached anything.  It's also best practice to show a bit of what you've already tried.  This is a community for collaboratively solving problems and creating a shared knowledge base and not a community for doing your work for you.

Comment: I would like to delete my question. please

Comment: You are not allowed to delete your question, it will be etched in infamy for all time. MWAH HAH HA

Comment: @PTTT You should have the option to do so underneath the tags under your question, but it might be better to edit the question by attaching the mentioned diagram and any attempts you've made so far.  We really do want to help, we just need some basic context to help us and we need you to give it a solid try to help you :)

Comment: yes you are right . so sorry for that :( Im so sorry

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL DB you can use the [new graph database capabilities](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/20/graph-data-processing-with-sql-server-2017/) and the new MATCH clause to answer queries like this, eg

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE ( 'User %s has skill %s and other skill %s.', [user1].[U-name], mainSkill.[S-name], otherSkill.[S-name] ) result
FROM 
    dbo.users user1, 
    dbo.hasSkill hasSkill1, dbo.skills mainSkill, dbo.hasSkill hasSkill2, dbo.skills otherSkill
WHERE mainSkill.[S-name] = 'CSS'
  AND otherSkill.[S-name] != mainSkill.[S-name]
  AND MATCH ( mainSkill<-(hasSkill1)-user1-(hasSkill2)->otherSkill);
```

My results:
[image: results]
Obviously you can answer the same queries with a relational approach, it's just a different way of doing things.  Full script available [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/4c21d819329e9a9a16aae1d9be6eef56).

Comment: Hi sir.. thank you for your beautiful answer . Is there a difference between cypher code in sql server 2017 and Neo4j? I saw your codes on Github and thank you for that .Can you write them with cypher query in Neo4j too? Thank you very very much. and another thing . You have wrote wonderful cypher codes I want to know the SQL query equivalent for them so that I can compare them with each other

Comment: At this point, the Cypher in SQL Server is only a subset of what's available in neo4j, but I expect the feature to improve.  We'll see ... ; )

Answer (score 0):

To make this more dynamic, replace the hard coded 'java' with a variable that you can pass to filter by any skill type, possibly make a stored procedure so you can pass the variable,
Edited column names as I didn't look at the image you provided:

```
--Outer query selects all skills of users which are not java and user has skill of java, 
--the inner query selects all user ids where the user has a skill of java    

SELECT sk.[SkillName], ui.[UserName], ui.[UserId]
FROM [dbo].[Skill] AS sk
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserSkill] AS us
ON us.[SkillId] = sk.[SkillId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserInfo] AS ui
ON ui.[UserId] = us.[UserId]
WHERE sk.[Skill] <> 'java' AND ui.[UserId] IN (
                                                SELECT [UserId]
                                                FROM [dbo].[UserInfo] ui
                                                INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserSkill] us
                                                ON us.[UserId] = ui.[UserId]
                                                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Skill] sk
                                                ON sk.[SkillId] = us.[SkillId]
                                                WHERE sk.[SkillName] = 'java')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but please take a look at my query too :)

Comment: @PTT If you are happy with my answer, please select it as the approved answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked well but what about my answer? is it better than my answer? in terms of performance and stuff

Comment: @PTTT I have no idea if one is better than the other as I don't have the data to test it. You could run both your query and my query and time it to see which is faster..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found

```
--Formatted query
select 
    o.UserName, k.SkillName
from 
    UserSkill S 
inner join 
    UserSkill SS on s.UserID = ss.UserID 
                 and s.SkillID = 1 
                 and ss.SkillID <> 1 
inner join 
    Skill k on k.SkillID = ss.SkillID
inner join 
    UsersINFO O on o.UserID = ss.UserID
```